# Unwarping 180 VR Footage with FFmpeg v360 Filter

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, virtual-reality, 360-virtual-reality

I am struggling at present.  I have searched high and low for days and can't find a command that achieves what we want to do.

We have stereoscopic 180 degrees VR footage in a side-by-side equirectangular format that we want to convert to flat so we can process using further AI software.

We have already split the file in half across the width using FFmpeg so we have a "right" eye and a "left" eye video file.

For each video file, we need to convert the 180-degree equirectangular footage to a flat, unwarped video file using FFmpeg (and the v360 filter).

We've tried the following for example:

```
ffmpeg -i 2LEFT.mp4 -vf "v360=input=equirect:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:output=flat" 2LEFTTEST.mp4
```

However, this results in a very warped/misaligned video.

Some command examples, tips, suggestions as to convert the now monoscopic 180-degree equirectangular footage to a flat video file will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "flat"? Equirectangular IS flat! It is the planar projection of a sphere. Posting some sample images would help understanding.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a similar problem. Here is the solution: If your video is already split into left and right views just use:

```
ffmpeg -i 2LEFT.mp4 -vf "v360=input=hequirect:output=flat" 2LEFTTEST.mp4
```

That differs from command you tried to use in a type of projection. Usually VR180 utilizes half-equirect projection for each eye.

Personally, I recommend for YouTube videos setting the output field of view and resolution:

```
ffmpeg -i 2LEFT.mp4 -vf "v360=input=hequirect:output=flat:h_fov=100:v_fov=67.5:w=1280:h=720" 2LEFTTEST.mp4
```

Finally, using filter_complex, you can immediately cut the video into left and right views in one command if you want to:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]v360=input=hequirect:output=flat:h_fov=100:v_fov=67.5:in_stereo=sbs:out_stereo=sbs:w=1280:h=720[flat];[flat]split[left][right];[left]stereo3d=sbsl:ml[left_mono];[right]stereo3d=sbsl:mr[right_mono]" -map [left_mono] 2LEFTTEST.mp4 -map [right_mono] 2RIGHTTEST.mp4
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Egor.  We have tested the first command you suggested however it only grabs the middle focus section of the original hequirect footage.  We need to be able to unwarp the entire shot (flatten/unwrap it).  Is this possible?  We will then make edits, upscale, and then re-warp back to hequirect.

Comment: Hi, @TedWilmont. You cannot make the entire shot flat, because by projecting a hemisphere in a plane, a significant loss of information will occur, and the reverse warp will become impossible. [Earth globe may be a good analogy](https://gisgeography.com/map-projections/). Despite this, upscaling may work well in a half-equirect projection. Other edits, such as text adding, may exist in special editors for VR180.

Comment: I tried your first suggestions but it cropped the video and I only got maybe 25 % of the centre of the picture. The original video is a VR-video 4320x2160 intended to be watched on a cellphone in one of those headsets where you mount the cellphone in front of your eyes. I don't know what perspective it is but everything (?) is very distorted.